# Do not turn off error in my page

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I am using

```
error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_NONE);
ini_set("display_errors", "off");
ini_set("display_errors", 0);
```

But error still show on my page

```
Warning: xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: A much better alternative would be to address and fix the errors you are facing, simply ignoring them is never a good idea.

Comment: @Hasan check the example in manual:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks to all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There's no `E_NONE` in php.
2. There's no `display_error`, only [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are getting a warning..Which produced by E_WARNING..It may be thrown because of a failed db connection..Execution of script will not be halted but it maybe still a problem..

http://php.net/manual/errorfunc.constants.php

If it's a db connection warning writing exceptions is a good practice

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

if you want to ignore warnings try:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
```

but please don't use `error_reporting(0);`

Because these are errors,you need to fix them,and the execution of the script will be halted

Use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

in development..